# How can I use String form of file instead of sh format file for bash

Tags: bash, terminal

Currently I am running my commands with a sh file type with bash command in macOS Terminal like this:

```
bash test.sh
```

And as you know that code works, Now I want give the inside value of test.sh which is some line String and trying to make it work, without having to present the file format of my commands.

lets say test.sh has this codes:

```
echo "Hello, world!"
ls
```

Now I want run the code like this sudo code in below:

```
bash """ echo "Hello, world!"; ls """
```

My goal is to get rid of the idea of using a sh file. All my goal is this: If sh file gives the strings or texts or commands, I want do the same thing with this deference that a String or a big String gave all commands to bash and I want put sh file out of action.

how can I do this?

Comment: The ".sh" extension doesn't mean anything. It's the file's contents that determine its "type".

Comment: However: `contents=$(< test.sh); bash -c "$contents"` or `bash < test.sh` or `cat test.sh | bash`

Comment: If you're trying to hide the commands from some person who wants to read your code, bash is the wrong language for that.

Comment: I am not trying to hide, I want make a shortcut, I was trying to say why we need 2 steps? 1.making a sh file, 2. leading bash to that file for reading strings. Instead making it in one step! given the strings to bash. Is it possible?

Comment: `bach` and `bash` are not the same command.

Comment: Is [this](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-source-command/) what you mean?  It's called "sourcing a file" and can be initiated either using the sh keyword `source` or the `.` syntax.  See embedded link or ask more if I am on to what you are looking for.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: thanks for the Link, that was good one, but my goal is to get rid of the idea of using a sh file, in your link still need a sh file. All my goal is this: If sh file gives the strings or texts or commands, I want do the same thing with this deference that a String or a big String gave all commands to bash and I want put sh file out of action.

Comment: As @glennjackman points out, there is not such thing as an "sh file" in linux.  The file extension is a (handy) construct that came from MS-DOS.  From the last example you show in the question, are you looking for `bash -c (commands here)` ?  For instance bash -c "ls" ?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Maybe that is what I am looking, I tried your code like this `bash -c (echo "Hello, world!" ls)` but it did not work, maybe I used it in wrong way.

Comment: `bash -c "echo ""hello world"" ; ls"`  you need a delimiter to separate commands in bash.  You also need to use one of many methods to provide inner quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you should consider less "send commands to bash" and more "execute a program"

- instead of calling your program `test.sh`, call it `mytest` with *no extension*.
- make sure it starts with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` so that the OS knows it needs to use bash to execute it
- make it executable: `chmod a+x mytest`
- invoke it like `/path/to/mytest`

  - or move it into a directory in your PATH, and invoke it just with `mytest`

Now, you don't need to worry about whether it's a "sh file" or not: it's just another executable program on your system.